# MediatR conventions in CQRS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, cqrs, mediatr

I am using MediatR and CQRS in a real project using the Clean Architecture principles.

Is it correct to:

1. Call `Command` from `NotificationHandler`?
2. Call `Command` in `Command`?
3. Call `Query` in `Command`?

If you have some resource for these principle, please share them with me.

Answer (score 2):

MediatR is a simple mediator pattern implementation in .NET as it keeps things separated and contributes to **Single Responsibility Principle**.

And CQRS stands for **Command and Query Responsibility Segregation**, which results in a pattern separating both read and write to maximize performance and scalability.

MediatR has 2 types of messages:

1. Request and response messages that will dispatch a single handler
2. Notification messages that will dispatch multiple handlers

**Requests** describe your commands and query behavior as they are fairly simple and specific.

**Handler** is what you will need to manage/solve a request. Where each request has its own handler.

**Commands** are where you will perform Insert, Update, and Delete operations.

**Queries** are where you will perform read operations **only**.

**Notifications** is where you will manage/solve a single request by using multiple handlers. So in this case you will create a **notification message** and create the corresponding handlers for your notification.

Remember that you should know the engineering functionalities of your application and based on it decide whether to use a request/response message or notification message. And more importantly, do not try to mix and match these 2 types of messages as you wish because you will break the mean of these patterns.

So my question is why would you need to call a command from the notification handler? and why do you want to mix 2 commands? and why would you mix the read and writes of your application?

**If you understand the 2 types of messaging in MediatR you will know the answer to your question and for any future questions**

Some great Resources:

[Use MediatR in ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core](https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/use-mediatr-in-asp-net-or-asp-net-core-cqrs-and-mediator-in-dotnet-how-to-use-mediatr-cqrs-aspnetcore-5076e2f2880c)

[Intro to MediatR - Implementing CQRS and Mediator Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yozD5Tnd8nw)

[Clean ASP.NET Core API using MediatR and CQRS | Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzOBrVlthMk)

This video talks about notifications: [The 2 MediatR features people don't know about but should](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TT3suofNlo)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a complex query(Suppose get customers by many filter) and i need this customers in multiple `CommandHandler`. 
I don't want to repeat this complex query in all `CommandHandlers`,
What can i do? repeat this complex query?

Comment: do you mean something like this [Mediatr with generic handler and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504374/mediatr-with-generic-handler-and-query)?

Comment: No suppose i have this method: 
``` 
Public List<Customer> GetCustomer()
{
    //Complex Where Clause => 40 Line
   return CustomerList;
} 

``` 

I use this in `CreateGroupCommandHandler`:

```
public class CreateGroupCommandHandler
{
   public async Task<Unit> Handle()
   {
       var customers= GetCustomer();
       // insterCustomerGroup
   }
}
```

and i use this method `GetCustomer` in multiple CommandHandler.

I unstrand your answer thank you, But what is your suggest in this situation.

Comment: what about using notifications so it can use the corresponding handler? just like the 4th resource I have included in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Mediator handlers, commands, queries and notifications should follow the Single responsibility principle (SRP). They should do as little as possible, be atomical. Calling other commands, queries or notifications within a handler is a bad habit as it creates coupling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i completely undrstand idea behind this principle.
I have another question. If i have a method with 30-40 line code that will be return `Customer List` and need this method in multiple Command Handler . what can i do? copy/pase this method in all Command Handlers?

Comment: @Ahmad You can add a request property of `IEnumerable<Customer>` to your Command and use that property in your handler. Also, it is fine to call services, data contexts from within your Handler, just don't call other handlers/commands

Comment: Your means of service is external service? like `Email Sender`? @klekmek

Answer (score 0):

> If you have some resource for these principle please share with me.

A great resource is this video [Intro to MediatR - Implementing CQRS and Mediator Patterns](https://youtube.com/watch?v=yozD5Tnd8nw)

The Commands are for Insert, Update and Delete operations where as the Queries are for Reads:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my quastion is: can we call a `Command` like 'CreateAccountCommand' in your picture, in a `NotificationHandler`?
what about another `Command` ? @jeremy-thompson